# how to display the smallest value in my code in emu8086?

Tags: emu8086

I had made a code that display the largest but then my teacher ask us to make another one that input 3 numbers and display the smallest value.

here is the code:

```
org 100h

    jmp start

    msg1 db 10,13,"Enter first number: $"
    msg2 db 10,13,"Enter second number: $"
    msg3 db 10,13,"Enter third Number: $"

    num1 db ?
    num2 db ?
    num3 db ?

start:

    lea dx, msg1
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    mov num1, al 
    lea dx, msg2
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    mov ah, 1 
    int 21h
    mov num2, al
    lea dx, msg3
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    mov num3, al

    mov bl, num1
    cmp bl, num2
    jng number2 

    cmp bl, num3
    jng number3

    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, num1
    int 21h
    jmp escape 

number2:

    mov bl, num2
    cmp bl, num3
    jng number3

    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, num2
    jmp escape

number3:

    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, num3
    int 21h

escape:
    ret
```

> sample output:
>
> 1st no. i enter 3
>
> 2nd no, i enter 2
>
> 3rd no, i enter 1
>
> and the largest is 3 but the output will be 13 because i don't know how to put space on my code :D...

Pls help!!! XD Also it's my first time posting this... so sorry for my bad grammar ty.

Comment: this is due in Monday hahhaha. danm.

Comment: Does your teacher know random strangers are doing your assignments?

Comment: @takendarkk : Fifoernik isn't random, I would have expected him to answer or Sep Roland. If I can guess, it probably isn't entirely random ;-)

Comment: w8... is it legal to give my code to strangers and fix it? or maybe better do my assignment. hahaha!!! seriously is it legal? O.o

Comment: also it's alright to ask question because they let us use the internet at school. so thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> mov ah, 2
> mov dl, num2
> jmp escape
> ```

In this part your program forgot to actually call DOS with `int 21h`.

> i don't know how to put space on my code

Just use the following everywhere you need some space between outputs on the same line:

```
mov ah, 2
mov dl, " "
int 21h
```

Or put items on different lines using:

```
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 10
int 21h
mov dl, 13
int 21h
```

A nicer solution would be to display a suitable message before outputting the number:

```
msg4 db 10,13,"Smallest value: $"
...
lea dx, msg4
mov ah, 9
int 21h
```

> my teacher ask us to make another one that input 3 numbers and display the smallest value.

Simply change all of those `jng` (jump on not greater) instructions by the `jnl` (jump on not less) instruction.

---

This is a slightly better version of your code and using `jnl`:

```
 mov bl, num1
 cmp bl, num2
 jnl number2 
 cmp bl, num3
 jnl number3
 mov dl, num1
 jmp Print
number2:
 mov bl, num2
 cmp bl, num3
 jnl number3
 mov dl, num2
 jmp Print
number3:
 mov dl, num3
Print:
 mov ah, 2    
 int 21h
 ret
```

---

Good luck monday!